# Where not equals not filtering anything out

Tags: sas, where-clause, proc-sql

I'm trying to filter out certain values from a table by using WHERE <> in PROC SQL. The query runs without errors, but doesn't actually filter anything out.

```
ID   Category   Sub_Category
1    Food       Vegetables
2    Food       Chicken
3    Appliance  Mixer
```

The code I have looks like this:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE APPLIANCE AS 
SELECT * FROM GENERAL_TABLE
WHERE Sub_Category <> "Chicken"
OR Sub_Category <> "Vegetables";
RUN;
```

I know I can switch the where statement to be WHERE = "Mixer" but I'd like to understand why WHERE <> isn't filtering anything out.

Comment: I would avoid using `<>` as an operator in SAS.  It might work in SQL code, but if you use that symbol in regular SAS code it has a different meaning.  *The MAX (<>) operator returns the higher of the two values.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `AND` not `OR`.

`OR` means if at least one condition is true, then it will display that row. Since one of those conditions will always be true, it will display all rows.

Rather than the `<>` and `OR`, use `IN` or `NOT IN`

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE APPLIANCE AS 
SELECT * FROM GENERAL_TABLE
WHERE Sub_Category not in ("Chicken", "Vegetables");
RUN;
```